# Cannot create table in database and insert data

Tags: php, sql

```
 <form id="login" name="login-form" method="POST" action="add.php">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">User Email Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email address" id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-add" name="add">Add</button>

</form>
```

add.php

```
   <?php 
  include 'config/database.php';
  include 'functions.php';
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = $_POST['password'];
  addUser($user, $pass, $con);
?>
```

functions.php

```
if (!function_exists('addUser')) {
    function addUser($user, $pass, $link){

      if(isset($_POST)){
      $user = sanitize($user, "varchar", $link);
      $pass = hash('sha256', $pass);
      $userTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'user'(
          'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
          'email' varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
          'pass' varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL)";

      if(!$con->query($userTable)){
        echo "Table is created successfully";
      }
      else{
        echo "error: executing table";
      }

      $query = "INSERT INTO $userTable(email, pass) VALUES('?','?')";
      $result = $link->prepare($query);
      $result->bind_param('ss', $user, $pass);
      $result->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

Tested INSert without function and it worked. Then move in function.
Create table seems not to work. Kept on adding users for test and see no new data added. Not sure where I went wrong. Appreciate help

Comment: You say "seems not to work".  Do you have any error messages?  Have you debugged to ensure you're not catching and ignoring the error?  Have you connected directly to the database to check the existence and/or the state of the table?

Comment: Looks like your addUser function accepts `$link` which you later reference as `$con` (in the if statement)

Comment: @MatBailie - I tried try, catch and finally but it gave me error that try catch finally cannot be used. and yes connect to database and check for its existence. I am learning php and I am seeing blank page and no error printed

Comment: @dale - yes I wanted to remove $link but how? because it will not run query without calling $link

Answer (score 1):

In your function try changing this

```
if(!$con->query($userTable)){
    echo "Table is created successfully";
}
```

To

```
if(!$link->query($userTable)){
    echo "Table is created successfully";
}
```

Comment: corrected and it does not create table at all. Couldnt figure why